Which Old World ROM machines could officially run OS X?
The Wikipedia article SuperDrive–Floppy disk drive section, contains (at the time of writing) the following claim:

The end of the SuperDrive coincides with the demise of Old World ROM Macs; with the advent of the New World ROM machines, Apple stopped offering internal floppy drives on all models. The SuperDrive is not supported in Mac OS X, not even on the few Old World ROM machines that can officially run OS X.

What were the "few Old World ROM machines that can officially run OS X"?

The only systems with an Old World ROM and official support for Mac OS X are the first generation of Power Macintosh G3 (“Beige”) systems and the second generation of PowerBook G3s. The second generation of Power Macintosh G3s, “Blue & White”, introduced New World ROMs.
Mac OS X Panther (10.3) dropped support for Old World ROM systems.
